# how to install eclipse Ditto

Tags: maven, docker, eclipse-ditto

I am trying to install Eclipse Ditto on my Ubuntu 18 machine, Maven and OpenJDK version "1.8.0_222", Docker version 18.09.7 are installed.
When running the command:

```
mvn clean install -Pdocker-build-image \
    -Ddocker.daemon.url=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

I get the following error:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.155 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-21T11:16:47+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "docker-build-image" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/home/samia). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.MissingProjectException: The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/home/samia). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Samia, do you really wish to build the docker images yourself? Or are you trying to start the ditto docker images?

Answer (score 2):

In order to "install" Ditto, you don't have to build it yourself (so you don't need to do `mvn clean install`).
Please have a look at the [Running Ditto](https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/installation-running.html) guide. 
The simplest way is to just start it with Docker compose liked documented there.

You can find other options for deployment [here](https://github.com/eclipse/ditto/tree/master/deployment) (e.g. Kubernetes, OpenShift, deployment via Helm).